# Correct way to add new elements in component with Vue in inline-template

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component which lists 6 images via PHP in an inline-template. When I click a 'load more' button, it makes an ajax call and receives more posts to be appended to the images list.

How should I implement that? I did it simply appending a template string with JS, but now I need to add an event listener on this image, which I can't using only template string.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understood well what the outcome should be, but from what I understood you have an action which will load some images from server side and you want to append them to your template; I will try to draft a solution, what comes to my mind.

- first you need an **array as holder** for the images in your view model.
- you will have to **update this array**, to add the new elements when you press on more button.
- you have to loop through the array and **display your images** in the template with v-for.
- when the array will be changed it normally should update the template as well. (check the [documentation for this](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods))

**template**

```
<template>
  <div v-for"image in allImages">
    ... display your images here...
  </div>
</template>
```

**Script**

```
data: {
  allImages: []
},
created() {
  // this will do the php call and update your array before the component is shown. So, it will your default.
  getMoreImages();
},
methods: {
 // Assuming this is a server call which receive a response with images...
 getMoreImages(response) {
   var newImages = response.newImages;
   this.allImages.push(newImages);
 }
}
```

I hope I understood you well, and this answer will help.

**Update:** here you have a [JS Fiddle example of what I mean](https://jsfiddle.net/bvqpts1c/) check the new fiddle please.

Comment: That's almost what I needed. That really looks like the correct way to do it and I had reached a similar solution, but as I said, I have default images that are fetched via PHP when the page loads, it's not like in your example where you only have one `v-for` and it will load the images based on the array, my images should be loaded first from PHP and then from this array, is this correct? Because it will look quite odd to have like 2 templates, one in PHP and the other using `v-for`, do you understand me?

Comment: You can fetch your data onCreated method and push them to the array, so this will be your default images. and then use same approach as in my example. I will update the answer

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that, but then my images will be loaded from JS, and I wanted it to be loaded with the document via PHP, that's the focus of the whole problem. It looks weird to have both the PHP and Vue image templates, but I don't see other way of doing this other than loading everything with Vue (that's also the reason why I'm using inline-template).